Users unable to see google add-in installed by the admin
I have created an add-on for Google Drive using App Script. The add-on works as designed using the Test Deployment feature. Now I have listed the internal app with Marketplace SDK. It's configured as an Admin install only. I have installed the app on the domain to a specific OU. Users in that OU are still unable to see the add-on in Drive.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Where can't they see the app? Only admins (and unsigned users) can see admin-only apps in the Marketplace. But if the app is installed they should see it in the corresponding host(s).

I started from a fresh project, and now users can see the add-on icon in the right side-panel of Drive. Sorry folks. False alarm.
